# Apply CSS on hintText of DatePicker Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I’m using Material-ui to build a booking system. In my DatePicker my hintText is white and barely visible and I want to change to color to black. I have used examples for my code from
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/3753 and https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/5737

I have also tried the example from Material-ui website but that didn’t either work. Im not getting any errors, it’s not just working.  Anybody have clue what I can do?

```
<div className="center-container">
    <DatePicker inputStyle={{color: 'black'}} hintText="Date..."                 
                           mode="landscape" minDate={new Date()}/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property `hintStyle`, we can use that to set the style of `hintText`.

Like this:

```
<DatePicker
    autoOk={false} 
    mode="landscape"
    hintText='please'
    hintStyle={{color:'red'}}
/>
```

Check the **[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/qd3z6Lze/)**.